# Powershell Script Service Check

Tags: powershell

I am trying to put together a script that I will be used to check and see if a service is running on the local machine. If it is then it will run an exe to launch a program. If it is not it needs to start the service then run the program after it starts. I think I am close just having issues if the service is not running.

```
If((Get-Service -Name ServiceName*).Status -eq 'Running') 
    {Invoke-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Application.exe"}
Else 
    {(Start-Service -Name ServiceName*) , (Invoke-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Application.exe")}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What errors are you getting? what happens if you run it in the ISE? :)

Comment: To long to post but in short it is griping about the Service not running as it is trying to start the application first as opposed to starting the service then launching the app.

Comment: I believe it is trying to run both the Start Service and the Invoke at the same time. The service should really be started and running then the Invoke command be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6) instead of [`Invoke-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-item?view=powershell-6). The script below successfully works on my machine and launches a dummy exe that just shows a WPF window:

$serviceName = "service_name"
$pathToExe = "c:\path\to\file.exe"

```
if ( (Get-Service -Name $serviceName).Status -eq 'Running' ){
    Start-Process $path
}else{
    Try{
        Start-Process -Name $serviceName -ErrorAction Stop
        Start-Process $path
    }catch{
        Write-Host "Failed to start service!"
    }
}
```

Let me know if that works for you :)

Comment: This may work though my new dilemma with this issue is our users are not local admins to their machines and not able to key in any domain or local credentials. If you could adjust this to where i could store the local admin account within the script for when the service is not running that would be fantastic.

Comment: @DarkLordWhite that’s probably not a good idea. However, there are plenty of example online and on SO showing secure credential storage. Since this is a different question to your original, you could create a new one asking this specific question :)

Answer (score 0):

Well if I run this script as an Administrator through Powershell it actually works....